# MapKit does not have sandbox access

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mkmapview, mapkit

I want to display a map on iphone so its run well but sandbox error is there.
I import mapKit. Then I used `@IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!` in `Main.storyboard`. I used Map Kit View.

So when I run it's builds and runs well and I get an error.
The error log is in below

> pid 393 (map) does not have sandbox access for frZQaeyWLUvLjeuEK43hmg
>   and IS NOT appropriately entitled
>
> libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:550: no access to InverseDeviceID
>   (see  rdar://problem/11744455)

Comment: Are you asking for permission before map load ?

Comment: it says there is an error the error log given above

Comment: can you share some code ?

Comment: pid 384 (mapp) does not have sandbox access for frZQaeyWLUvLjeuEK43hmg and IS NOT appropriately entitled
2017-08-24 15:53:39.802068+0530 mapp[384:60087]